# Django Form is not submitting, even though it seems to be working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

My form is still not submitting. I am stressed out now, I am rebuilding my app from the ground up because a form wasn't working (in total I have three, the other two did work), and it still isn't working. I did use the same model, so maybe it has something to do with it. That or it has something to do with two fields, the ones that are foreign keys of the other two forms. Anyway here is my code if you could check it out:

```
#models.py
class Contratos(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    contractor=models.ForeignKey(Vendors, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contractee=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    start=models.DateField()
    end=models.DateField()
    cost=models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    blank=''
    Pesos= 'PE'
    Dolares='DL'
    CURR_CHOICES= [
        (blank, '----'),
        (Pesos, 'MXN'),
        (Dolares, 'DLLS'),
        ]
    currency=models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=CURR_CHOICES,
        default=None,
        )
    def is_upperclass(self):
        return self.currency in {self.Pesos, self.Dolares}
    Producto12='PR'
    Servicio= 'SE'
    Poliza='PO'
    Lic='LC'
    Otro='OT'
    TIPO_CHOICES= [
        (blank, '----'),
        (Producto12, 'Product'),
        (Servicio, 'Service'),
        (Poliza, 'Policy'),
        (Lic, 'Licensing'),
        (Otro, 'Other'),
        ]
    type=models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=TIPO_CHOICES,
        default=None,
        )
    def is_upperclass(self):
        return self.type in {self.Servicio, self.Otro}
    IT='IT'
    Fin='FN'
    Rec='RH'
    Man='MT'
    Cua='CR'
    depc_CHOICES= [
        (IT, 'IT'),
        (blank, '----'),
        (Fin, 'Finance'),
        (Rec, 'Human Resources'),
        (Man, 'Maintenance'),
        (Cua, 'Rooms'),
        ]
    department=models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=depc_CHOICES,
        default=NONE,
        )
    def is_upperclass1(self):
        return self.department in {self.IT, self.Cua}

    description =models.TextField()
    product=models.ForeignKey(assets,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attached_file=models.FileField(blank=True)
    notification=models.BooleanField(default=False)

#forms.py
class ContractsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contratos
        fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {
            
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs ={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'contractee': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'contractor': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'contractor_view' }),
            'start': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'date'}),
            'end': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'date'}),
            'cost': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'currency':forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select'}),
            'type': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select'}),
            'department': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select' , 'disabled': 'true'}),
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 3}),
            'product': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'product_view'}),
            'attached_file': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'notification': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check-input'}),
            }
#views.py
def contract_form(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
            form = ContractsForm()
            return render(request,"contracts_form.html", {'form':form})
    else:
        form = ContractsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('/contracts')


#urls.py
    path('contracts/add', views.contract_form, name = 'new-contract'),

#contracts_form.html
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off" class="row g-3">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{form}}
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right;">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

So yeah, I had already asked for something similar but the answers there didn't help at all and maybe this question can reach more people.

Comment: in contactractor form, add POST instead of GET

Comment: Add an else statement to your `if form.is_valid()` and add `print(form.errors)`

Comment: Thank you @joshlsullivan this helped me out, I have no debugging experience. Yeah, console said one of my fields was missing, and in the html I had a disabled selection for that, so it took it like a blank field. Thanks!!

Comment: @MarioA you're welcome. Just comes with years of trial and error.